# Create new column from multiple columns where value that is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm trying to create a new column from 4 multiple columns that start with the same name. Either 3 or 4 out of these columns are NaN. I'd like to have the new column to have this non-NaN value, if it exists in the particular row. Otherwise the new column should be NaN.

Start with:

```
    NaN = np.NaN
    pd.DataFrame( {'process_time_1': [5, NaN, NaN, NaN], 'process_time_2': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], 
    'process_time_3': [NaN, NaN, 3, 4], 'process_time_4': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]} )
```

if would like the new column to look like:

```
    NaN = np.NaN
    pd.DataFrame( {'process_time': [5, NaN, 3, 4]} )
```

The code I currently have:

```
    cols =  [df1.columns.str.startswith('process')]
    df1[cols][df1.notna()]
```

I'm breaking my head of this, would be great if somebody could help into the right direction:)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is always only one non NaN values per rows?

Comment: yes this is correct. All columns are imported and there are 4 silo's.

Comment: Raw data is stored like this

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) here to forward fill with the valid values, and just keep the last column:

```
df['process_time'] = df.filter(like='process').ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]

print(df)
   process_time_1  process_time_2  process_time_3  process_time_4  \
0             5.0             NaN             NaN             NaN   
1             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN   
2             NaN             NaN             3.0             NaN   
3             NaN             NaN             4.0             NaN   

   process_time  
0           5.0  
1           NaN  
2           3.0  
3           4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max` along `axis=1`:

```
df['process_time'] = df.filter(like='process').max(1)
```

---

```
   process_time_1  process_time_2  process_time_3  process_time_4  process_time
0             5.0             NaN             NaN             NaN           5.0
1             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN           NaN
2             NaN             NaN             3.0             NaN           3.0
3             NaN             NaN             4.0             NaN           4.0
```

Comment: you are a minute faster than me :) +1

Comment: Thanks @AndyL. and sorry for that :-)

Comment: @jezrael dude check the question its mentioned there `Either 3 or 4 out of these columns are NaN`

Comment: First i deep thinking about it, ya, it is same like only one maximal non NaN value.